Laravel 11.x SQL injection
Is it safe to use the following validation rule in Laravel 11.x?
"required|string|unique:table,column,NULL,id,field,{$request->value}"

Regardless of the context or the possibility of using other validation types, is this approach safe from SQL injection? Could someone please provide a reference to this in the Laravel documentation?

This looks like a validation rule, which has nothing to do with SQL injection. It may also not work the way you expect. gt expects a field or value, so if you're checking to make sure that the value is greater than another field in the input, then use the field name.

Sorry my bad, I gave a basic example but I had to pick something that actually has something to do with sql, I have updated the validation rule, but the point is still the same, kindly ignore everything except for actually having a hardcoded $request->value inside the string validation rule, so the question is as basic as whether it's safe or not

That is too many things for the unique rule. unique only expects the table name and column name. Anything beyond that would need a custom rule using the Rule class

You really freaked me out hh, it's working it's just not well documented, please refer to the small paragraph above this one: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#rule-uppercase (Adding Additional Where Clauses)

@aynber it is valid, I just hate that it is not well documented, but it is the same using a string or the object, the object just has autocompletion: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/29acd212d3ed95c92111318e3f37d74a5c47c9b9/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Unique.php#L66-L75

@matiaslauriti Huh. Yeah, it's not documented at all. I didn't go digging into the code at all, just went off the documentation. Learn something new every day

I found this in laravel documentation:

You should never pass any user controlled request input into the
ignore method. Instead, you should only pass a system generated unique
ID such as an auto-incrementing ID or UUID from an Eloquent model
instance. Otherwise, your application will be vulnerable to an SQL
injection attack.

So, I believe it's the definitive answer for that, thanks for everyone :)
